# Can I use const & as parameter of a constexpr function?

Tags: c++11, constexpr, stdarray

I'm writing a constrexpr function taking either a `CArray T(&)(N)`, either a `std::array`.
I think I have to write 2 functions (if you know better I would be happy to know),

But I'm concerned about what I wrote with the std::array

```
    constexpr float LinInterp01(const std::array<float, N>& inArray, float inX);
```

**Is it correct when writing a constrexpr function to pass by const & or not?**

I think it should be because at compile time the compiler would instanciate a copy and there is no notion of L Value, at compile time.

**Could someone explain me this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ standard section § 7.1.5 [dcl.constexpr]

> The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following constraints:
>
> — it shall not be virtual (10.3);
>
> — its return type shall be a literal type;
>
> — each of its parameter types shall be a **literal type**;

And section  § 3.9 [basic.types]

> A type is a literal type if it is:
>
> — void; or
>
> — a scalar type; or
>
> — **a reference type**; or
>
> — an array of literal type; or
>
> — a class type (Clause 9) that has all of the following properties:
>
> — it has a trivial destructor,
>
> — it is an aggregate type (8.5.1) or has at least one constexpr constructor or constructor template
>   that is not a copy or move constructor, and
>
> — all of its non-static data members and base classes are of non-volatile literal types.

So **yes**, you can pass parameters by reference to `constexpr` functions.

Now whether or not your function calls will actually be evaluated at compile time depends on the body and calls of `LinInterp01`.

Comment: Thank you, the body of the function is ok, only doing basic maths and calling `std::array::size` which is constexpr. So it should be ok, but thank you for explaing this.

Comment: @dzada : No p. Note that even "basic maths" (e.g. if operated over several statements in c++11) might not be constexpr.

Comment: @quantadev : and why is that? if I do basic + - * / on floats, and access to a static array value, Ii expected it to be.